# Create a draggable element that will return to its original position when the user lifts their finger

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I'm working on implementing a draggable element using Android Jetpack Compose that will smoothly return to its original position when the user lifts their finger. I came to some implementation by I do not really like it.

```
@Composable
fun dragAndBack2() {
    var offset by remember { mutableStateOf(IntOffset.Zero) }
    var isAnimating by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

    var animate = animateIntOffsetAsState(
        targetValue = if (isAnimating) {
            IntOffset.Zero
        } else offset,
        animationSpec = tween(
            durationMillis = 1000,
            easing = LinearEasing
        ),
        finishedListener = {
            offset = IntOffset.Zero
        }

    )
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .offset { if (isAnimating) animate.value else offset }
            .pointerInput(Unit) {
                detectDragGestures(
                    onDragCancel = { isAnimating = true },
                    onDragStart = { isAnimating = false },
                    onDragEnd = { isAnimating = true },
                    onDrag = { change, dragAmount ->
                        change.consumeAllChanges()
                        val offsetChange =
                            IntOffset(dragAmount.x.roundToInt(), dragAmount.y.roundToInt())
                        offset = offset.plus(offsetChange)
                    }
                )
            }
            .background(Color.Blue)
            .size(50.dp)
    )
}
```

It works, but when the finger is lifted, the element jumps some distance away from the finger, as if it is jumping to the last saved position.

```
    @Composable
fun AnimatedBox() {
    var isAnimating by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    val transition = updateTransition(targetState = !isAnimating)

    var offset by remember { mutableStateOf(IntOffset.Zero) }

    val transitionOffset by transition.animateIntOffset(
        transitionSpec = {
            keyframes {
                durationMillis = 1000
                offset at 0 with LinearOutSlowInEasing // start value
                IntOffset.Zero at 500
            }
        },
        label = "boxSize"
    ) { b ->
        if (b) {
            offset
        } else {
            IntOffset.Zero
        }
    }

    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .offset { transitionOffset }
            .pointerInput(Unit) {
                detectDragGestures(
                    onDragStart = {
                        offset = IntOffset.Zero
                        isAnimating = false
                    },
                    onDragEnd = {
                        isAnimating = true
                    },
                    onDrag = { change, dragAmount ->
                        change.consumeAllChanges()
                        val offsetChange =
                            IntOffset(dragAmount.x.roundToInt(), dragAmount.y.roundToInt())
                        offset = offset.plus(offsetChange)
                    }
                )
            }
            .background(Color.Blue)
            .size(50.dp)
    )
}
```

It also works, but if the finger doesn't move, the element quickly moves back to its original position.
There is also some delay in both versions of the realization. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i solved it. Here is some delay between finger and element. But it works like I want.

```
        @Composable
    fun onTouchWithTransition(position: IntOffset, sizeDp: Dp) {

        val fingerPosition by remember { mutableStateOf(Position(position)) }
        val placeToReturn by remember { mutableStateOf(Position(position)) }

        var testTransition: Position by remember {
            mutableStateOf(fingerPosition)
        }

        var transition: Transition<Position> = updateTransition(targetState = testTransition)

        val transitionOffset by transition.animateIntOffset(
            transitionSpec = {
                keyframes {
                    durationMillis = 500
                }
            },
            label = "label"
        ) {
            it.offset
        }



        Box(modifier = Modifier
            .offset { transitionOffset }
            .clip(CircleShape)
            .background(Color.Red)
            .pointerInput(Unit) {
                detectDragGestures(
                    onDragStart = {
                        fingerPosition.offset = position
                        testTransition = fingerPosition
                    },
                    onDragEnd = { testTransition = placeToReturn },
                    onDrag = { change, dragAmount ->
                        change.consumeAllChanges()
                        val offsetChange =
                            IntOffset(dragAmount.x.roundToInt(), dragAmount.y.roundToInt())
                        fingerPosition.offset = fingerPosition.offset.plus(offsetChange)
                    }
                )
            }
            .size(sizeDp, sizeDp)
        )
    }


    class Position(private var off: IntOffset) {
        var offset: IntOffset by mutableStateOf(off)
    }
```